# Custom MKAnnotationView expandable without callout

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotationview

I want to create custom `MKAnnotationView` (with image) without a callout, but expandable after touch. Here is what i have in mind:

1) First the `MKAnnotation` looks like this:

[image]

2) Then after tap on it this should expand and looks like this:

[image]

I've started with customing `MKAnnotationView` and have a class:

`@interface CustomPinAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>`

The class have method:

```
-(MKAnnotationView*)annotationView {
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:self reuseIdentifier:@"AnnotationIdentifier"];
    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"star"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];

    return annotationView;
}
```

And what i try to do is set a customView as a subview to the `MKAnnotationView`, but when i don't set The image it will not responding (this is pretty logical after i've think about it), but got the feeling that I'm doing something very nasty here, and should be a way to override `MKAnnotationView` somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
   {
          enemyAnnotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"firstImage.png"];
   }

 -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
   {
          enemyAnnotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SecondImage.png"];
   }
```

Try like this first method is for the View for annotation that time your first image will be appears,

Second method will run when user select annotation

Comment: Oh, easy and perfect! I know i'm overenginering it :) Thanks!